# Flutter/Dart Shared Preferences DateTime getting converted

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I'm facing a weird issue with flutter shared prefs, 
I'm trying to set a DateTime.Now() object to shared preferences like this

```
    void setStartTimeDataToPrefs() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    prefs.setString(_prefsStartTime, DateTime.now().toString());

    print('Getting soon after setting in same function ${prefs.getString(_prefsStartTime)}');
    //Here im getting the value correct as 2020-06-17 11:32:17.548524
  }
```

To test when I read the key right after setting from the same function I get the expected result date converted to a string

> 2020-06-17 13:32:17.548524

The problem is when I try to read the key from another function like this,

```
  void getStartTimeDataFromPrefs() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    print('${prefs.getString(_prefsStartTime)}');
  }
```

It gives me this result

> 1:32:17 PM

Any idea of how the preferences data changed? How the date got formatted like it did a DateFormat.jms()

Also trying to understand why the same code is behaving in two different ways in different functions. It had the correct value when I read it in the first function?

Comment: I tried your code and the set method and get method give me the same result: 2020-06-17 11:00:27.533554

Comment: Maybe its local to me just trying to see if anyone has faced this before. thanks for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
//Insert
prefs.setInt('yourKey', DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch);
//Get
DateTime dt = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch((prefs.getInt('yourKey')??DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch);
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved it this way only. I posted the question to see if anyone has faced this before. but this event makes me question why shared preferences won't support one more data structure for DateTime.